# different behaviors on python for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Can someone please explain why the for loop acts differently in these 2 situations? (if it operates on a copy of the variable, why the values change in scenario 1? if not, why the values don’t change in scenario 2?

Scenario 1:

```
class Person:
  height = 100

people = []

for i in range(2):
  people.append(Person())

for i in people:
  print(i.height)

for i in people:
  i.height += 20

for i in people:
  print(i.height)
```

Results:

```
100
100
120
120
```

Scenario 2:

```
b = [1, 2, 3]

for i in b:
  i += 5

print(b)
```

Results:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Shouldn't it act the same way? I am confused!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: In your second scenario, the `i` variable is the value of the (immutable) integer item, not a reference to an object in the list.  So modifying `i` has no effect on the item at the corresponding position in the list.   It is not that for-loop behaves differently but the mutability of the item that causes this apparent difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with scenario 2 is that the `print(b)` is not located inside of the for loop. Also, you should be trying to print `i` not `b`.

The fixed code looks like this:

```
b = [1, 2, 3]

for i in b:
  i += 5
  print(i)
```

Output:

```
6
7
8
```

Comment: If you print ```b```, you will not get the ```i``` values that you just added 5 to.

Comment: That’s not the problem, the problem is that after running both loops, the actual value of people[0].height is 120 (not 100) but the value of b[0] is still 1 (not 6) the results are inconsistent. (Don’t focus on print, my problem is with the final values)

Comment: That's because you're editing the values of a class in scenario 1, not the values of a list like you are in scenario 2.

Comment: That’s exactly my question, so it means only in dealing with objects, the loop works on the reference and other than that it will be just a copy of the variable?

Comment: That's a good way to see it.